# Can't deploy Maven jars to S3 from Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, amazon-s3, maven-3

I'm trying to deploy a Maven jar to S3 from within IntelliJ (meaning, using the Maven Projects panel). This fails constantly, saying:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyProject: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact Project:MyProject:jar:1.0.0 from/to s3-spark.release (s3://MyS3): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain -> [Help 1]
```

But, when I try to do the same from within the terminal using `mvn deploy`, everything works great. Any ideas what am I missing? (Using Maven 3.3.9, IntelliJ Comumnity 2016.1)

Comment: better copy all the error message

Comment: Edited the question with the full error.

Comment: You are getting this exception because your AWS SDK is unable to load your credentials. What you should do is goto Preferences then goto AWS and add your secret key and access key. So that your project can retrieve both keys.

Comment: I don't see AWS on my File > Settings menu.. where is it located? Should I install something?